# Python 3.9.0 set as default on rasberry pi 4 but my IDE cant see it

Tags: python, linux, development-environment

I  was able to install python 3.9.0 on raspberry 4 and I can verify through the terminal that that has been set as the default python. However, 3 different IDEs (idle, thorny and Microsoft visual code) that I am using cannot find the python 3.9.0 but can see 3.7.3 which came with the pi. I followed this ([link](https://itheo.tech/install-python-3-9-on-raspberry-pi)) instruction but cannot tell why it is not working.
I will appreciate any help at all.
Thank you.

Comment: for VS Code you should [select the 3.9.0 interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment). i'm not familiar with the other IDEs but there's probably an analogous setting if you google like "idle select python interpreter."

Comment: I'm not sure but for `IDLE` you may have to install it with `python3.9 -m pip install idle` or `apt install idle-python3.9` and you should have to run it as `idle-python3.9` - so at the same time you should have `idle-python3.7` to run it with `Python 3.7`

Comment: `thonny` (similar to `VS Code`) has `Tools > Options > Interpreter` or `Run > Select Interpreter...`. You may also use `python3.9 -m pip install thonny` and it should even use `python3.9` to run `thonny`

Comment: Thank   @furas. The issue seem to have been solved  as I can now see python 3.9.0  among VS Code interpreters though I have not use it yet.  I messed up  the bash file by adding the line: PATH = "/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.0/bin $PATH" and now when I echo path, that is the only Path  I see. I am not able to edit the bash profile again. How can I undo that?

Comment: I saw the python 3.9.0 when I did what @tdy suggested though I was not seeing it before but now I do. The new is the PATH that is messed up.

Comment: you should add to existing `PATH` like `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.0/bin:$PATH`. As I remeber it has to be splited by `:` and it has to be `=` without spaces. You can check `echo $PATH` before you set new value to see if it uses `:` to separate paths

Comment: Thank @furas. I have added it and now working but the python 3.9.0 does not seem work with some libraries. I can use pip to install pandas and dash and it will say requirement already made. But If run `print("Hello")` and `import pandas as pd`. It will print  `Hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/MyProjects/hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`. I do not know where things went wrong.

Comment: you have to install `pandas` in `Python 3.9.0`. Check if you have `pip3.9` - `pip3.9 install pandas` - or use directly `python3.9` like `python3.9 -m pip install pandas`. Every `python` version should have own `pip` to install modules only for this version - they don't share modules. BTW: you could check `pip -V` and `pip3 -V` to see for what version they install modules.

Comment: Thank you @furas. I am trying this out though it is taking longer time. I used to think this python versions share libraries. I appreciate the clarification. I will update you how it goes.

Comment: Hey @furas, thank you so much. This your last comment answered my question and I am so happy now. How can I mark that comment as the answer?

Comment: I added all my comments as answer - so you can mark answer. I also added few additional information and links to other forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but for `IDLE` you may have to install it with

```
python3.9 -m pip install idle
```

or

```
apt install idle-python3.9
```

and you should have to run it as

```
idle-python3.9
```

so at the same time you should have

```
idle-python3.7
```

to run it with `Python 3.7`

---

`thonny` (similar to `VS Code`) has `Tools > Options > Interpreter` or `Run > Select Interpreter...`. You may also use

```
python3.9 -m pip install thonny
```

and it should even use `python3.9` to run `thonny`

---

You should add Python's folder to existing `PATH` like

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python-3.9.0/bin:$PATH.
```

As I remeber it has to be splited by `:` and it has to be `=` without spaces.

You can check

```
echo $PATH
```

before you set new value to see if it uses `:` to separate paths.

But usually it should create also links

```
/usr/bin/python3.7
/usr/bin/python3.9

/usr/bin/pip3.7
/usr/bin/pip3.9
```

so it should run without any changes in `PATH`.
At least I have these links on `Linux Mint 20` (based on `Ubuntu 20.04`).

You can check if you have

```
ls -al /usr/bin/python*
ls -al /usr/bin/pip*
```

and also

```
which python3.7
which python3.9

which pip3.7
which pip3.9
```

or

```
whereis python

whereis pip
```

or formatted (`new line` instead of `space`)

```
whereis python | sed 's/ /\n/g'

whereis pip | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

---

Eventually you could create link manually and then you don't have to add folder to PATH

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/python-3.9.0/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.9
```

or you could copy (not move) `python` to `/usr/bin/python3.9`

```
sudo cp /usr/local/opt/python-3.9.0/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.9
```

---

Every python version should have own `pip` to install modules only for this version - they don't share modules.

You have to install `pandas` in `Python 3.9.0`. Check if you have `pip3.9`

```
pip3.9 install pandas
```

or use directly `python3.9` like

```
python3.9 -m pip install pandas
```

You could check

```
pip -V 

pip3 -V
```

to see for what version they install modules.

---

**BTW:**

`Stackoverflow` has special page for `Raspberry Pi`

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

`Raspberry Pi` has also own official forum

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/

Comment: Many thanks @furas. This is really helpful.